# Parse Migration - Client to Client Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, cloud

We are trying to implement client to client push notifications as we migrate from Parse. Through other platforms, discussions, etc it seems that they way to do this is through cloud code - a couple of questions for the community -

1. Will we have to expose the Master Key in production?
2. Has one gotten the following scenario to work with some sample cloud code they could share:
   User X like's User Y's Object Z...User Y would receive the notification trigged by the action of User X in real time.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. The master key will be used only in your cloud code on the server side and will not be exposed to your clients so when you are calling the push api from cloud code you need to set **useMasterKey: true**
2. In order to send a push to your Y you need to do the following:

   - When you create the ParseInstallation in your client code make sure that you also save the user there in a column. You need to save the user inside the ParseInstallation because your requirement is to send push to one or more users so in order to know what devices this user have (one user can have multiple devices of course) you need to save a reference to the user inside the ParseInstallation class
   - Next you need to use the following code in order to send a push notification to the user:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("SendPush", function(request) {


  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("objectId", "{YOUR_USER_OBJECT_ID"});
/* here you get the user by it's id. if you have another identifier or you want to use another field you can change it. You can also add multiple conditions if you like */

// here you can add other conditions e.g. to send a push to sepcific users or channel etc.

var payload = {
  alert: "YOUR_MESSAGE"
    // you can add other stuff here...
};


Parse.Push.send({
  data: payload,
  where: query
}, {
  useMasterKey: true
})
.then(function() {
  response.success("Push Sent!");
}, function(error) {
  response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
});
});
```

**Please make sure you send the objectId of user Y from the client. In case you are not sending you will need to find a way to get it (maybe by fetching it from the DB)**

Comment: Thank you so much, Ran! I guess my major question is about getting all the disparate systems to speak to each other...like how will the Parse cloud code talk to MongoDB and all of that talk to AWS. But this is also helpful!